# Results from my thin plate spline interpolation implementation are dependant of the independent variables

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, interpolation

I implemented the [thin plate spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline) algorithm (see also [this description](http://profs.etsmtl.ca/hlombaert/thinplates/)) in order to interpolate scattered data using Python.

My algorithm seems to work correctly when the bounding box of the initial scattered data has an aspect ratio close to 1. However, scaling one of the data points coordinates changes the interpolation result. I created a minimal working example that is representative of what I am trying to accomplish. Below are two plots showing the results of the interpolation of 50 random points.

First, the interpolation of `z = x^2` on the domain `x = [0, 3], y = [0, 120]`:

[image: failed interpolation]

As you can see, the interpolation fails. Now, executing the same process but after scaling the `x` values by a factor of 40, I get:

[image: successful interpolation]

This time, the result looks better. Choosing a slightly different scaling factor would have resulted in a slightly different interpolation. This shows that something is wrong in my algorithm but I can't find what exactly. Here is the algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

# pts1 = Mx2 matrix (original coordinates)
# z1   = Mx1 column vector (original values)
# pts2 = Nx2 matrix (interpolation coordinates)

def gen_K(n, pts1):
    K = np.zeros((n,n))

    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            if i != j:
                r = ( (pts1[i,0] - pts1[j,0])**2.0 + (pts1[i,1] - pts1[j,1])**2.0 )**0.5
                K[i,j] = r**2.0*np.log(r)

    return K

def compute_z2(m, n, pts1, pts2, coeffs):   
    z2 = np.zeros((m,1))

    x_min = np.min(pts1[:,0])
    x_max = np.max(pts1[:,0])
    y_min = np.min(pts1[:,1])
    y_max = np.max(pts1[:,1])

    for k in range(0,m):
        pt = pts2[k,:]

        # If point is located inside bounding box of pts1
        if (pt[0] >= x_min and pt[0] <= x_max and pt[1] >= y_min and pt[1] <= y_max):
            z2[k,0] = coeffs[-3,0] + coeffs[-2,0]*pts2[k,0] + coeffs[-1,0]*pts2[k,1]

            for i in range(0,n):
                r2 = ( (pts1[i,0] - pts2[k,0])**2.0 + (pts1[i,1] - pts2[k,1])**2.0 )**0.5

                if r2 != 0:
                    z2[k,0] += coeffs[i,0]*( r2**2.0*np.log(r2) )

        else:
            z2[k,0] = np.nan

    return z2

gen_K_nb = nb.jit(nb.float64[:,:](nb.int64, nb.float64[:,:]), nopython = True)(gen_K)
compute_z2_nb = nb.jit(nb.float64[:,:](nb.int64, nb.int64, nb.float64[:,:], nb.float64[:,:], nb.float64[:,:]), nopython = True)(compute_z2)

def TPS(pts1, z1, pts2, factor):
    n, m = pts1.shape[0], pts2.shape[0]

    P = np.hstack((np.ones((n,1)),pts1))
    Y = np.vstack((z1, np.zeros((3,1))))

    K = gen_K_nb(n, pts1)
    K += factor*np.identity(n)

    L = np.zeros((n+3,n+3))
    L[0:n, 0:n] = K
    L[0:n, n:n+3] = P
    L[n:n+3, 0:n] = P.T

    L_inv = np.linalg.inv(L)
    coeffs = L_inv.dot(Y)

    return compute_z2_nb(m, n, pts1, pts2, coeffs)
```

Finally, here is the code snippet I used to create the two plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 50 # Number of random points

pts = np.random.rand(N,2)
pts[:,0] *= 3.0 # initial x values
pts[:,1] *= 120.0 # initial y values

z1 = (pts[:,0])**2.0

for scale in [1.0, 40.0]:

    pts1 = pts.copy()
    pts1[:,0] *= scale

    x2 = np.linspace(np.min(pts1[:,0]), np.max(pts1[:,0]), 40)
    y2 = np.linspace(np.min(pts1[:,1]), np.max(pts1[:,1]), 40)
    x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x2, y2)

    pts2 = np.vstack((x2.flatten(), y2.flatten())).T
    z2 = TPS(pts1, z1.reshape(z1.shape[0], 1), pts2, 0.0)

    # Display
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    C = ax.contourf(x2, y2, z2.reshape(x2.shape), np.linspace(0,9,10), extend='both')
    ax.plot(pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1], 'ok')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    plt.colorbar(C, extendfrac=0)
    plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thin Plate Spline is scalar invariant, which means if you scale x and y by the same factor, the result should be the same. However, if you scale x and y differently, then the result will be different.  This is common characteristics among radial basis functions. Some radial basis functions are not even scalar invariant.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it "fails", what do you mean? The big question is, does it still exactly interpolate at the construction points? Assuming your code is correct and you do not have ill-conditioning, it *should* in which case it does not fail.

What I think is happening is that the addition of the scale is making the behavior in the `x` direction more dominant so you do not see the wiggles that come naturally from the interpolation.

As an aside, you can greatly speed up your code without using Numba by vectorizing.

```
import scipy.spatial.distance
import scipy.special
def gen_K(n,pts1):
    # No need for n but kept to maintain compatability
    pts1 = np.atleast_2d(pts1)
    r = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(pts1,pts1)
    return scipy.special.xlogy(r**2,r)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you will get horrible ridges running through the surface. Resulting in a sub-optimal model fit. Read the caption below the images. Your model is experiencing the same effect, although plotted in 2D.

[image: Thin Plate Spline vs. Tensor Product Smooth]